# zypper (and yast) no longer working after upgrade from openSUSE 15.3 to 15.4

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I upgraded a laptop from openSUSE 15.3 to 15.4 today. During the process, there were many prompts related to requirements that could not be provided.

After running the upgrade process, fixing a number of repo URLs and rebooting, both `sudo zypper verify` and `sudo zypper ref && sudo zypper up` give the following error message:

```
zypper: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libzypp.so.1722: undefined symbol: _ZN4YAML6detail9node_data12empty_scalarB5cxx11
```

I have also noticed that in Yast, I can't get beyond the first screen: when I click "Software Management" or any of the other items in the control centre, the throbber spins for a few seconds but nothing else happens.

Output of `rpm -q libzypp`:

```
libzypp-17.31.2-150200.45.1.x86_64
```

Output of `rpm -q zypper`:

```
zypper-1.14.57-150200.39.1.x86_64
```

Output of `rpm -q -i libzypp zypper`:

```
Name        : libzypp
Version     : 17.31.2
Release     : 150200.45.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri 14 Oct 2022 19:24:59 CEST
Group       : System/Packages
Size        : 10145384
License     : GPL-2.0-or-later
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 06 Oct 2022 16:21:42 CEST, Key ID 70af9e8139db7c82
Source RPM  : libzypp-17.31.2-150200.45.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 06 Oct 2022 16:15:12 CEST
Build Host  : sheep16
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : https://www.suse.com/
Vendor      : SUSE LLC <https://www.suse.com/>
URL         : https://github.com/openSUSE/libzypp
Summary     : Library for package, patch, pattern and product management
Description :
libzypp is the package management library that powers applications
like YaST, zypper and the openSUSE/SLE implementation of PackageKit.

libzypp provides functionality for a package manager:

  * An API for package repository management, supporting most common
    repository metadata formats and signed repositories.
  * An API for solving packages, products, patterns and patches
    (installation, removal, update and distribution upgrade
    operations) dependencies, with additional features like locking.
  * An API for commiting the transaction to the system over a rpm
    target. Supporting deltarpm calculation, media changing and
    installation order calculation.
  * An API for browsing available and installed software, with some
    facilities for programs with an user interface.
Distribution: SUSE Linux Enterprise 15
Name        : zypper
Version     : 1.14.57
Release     : 150200.39.1
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri 14 Oct 2022 19:25:00 CEST
Group       : System/Packages
Size        : 8306495
License     : GPL-2.0-or-later
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 06 Oct 2022 16:31:56 CEST, Key ID 70af9e8139db7c82
Source RPM  : zypper-1.14.57-150200.39.1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 06 Oct 2022 16:30:31 CEST
Build Host  : sheep28
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : https://www.suse.com/
Vendor      : SUSE LLC <https://www.suse.com/>
URL         : https://github.com/openSUSE/zypper
Summary     : Command line software manager using libzypp
Description :
Zypper is a command line tool for managing software. It can be used to add
package repositories, search for packages, install, remove, or update packages,
install patches, hardware drivers, verify dependencies, and more.

Zypper can be used interactively or non-interactively by user, from scripts,
or front-ends.

Authors:
--------
    Jan Kupec <jkupec@suse.cz>
    Michael Andres <ma@suse.de>
    Duncan Mac-Vicar <dmacvicar@suse.de>
    Martin Vidner <mvidner@suse.cz>
    Josef Reidinger <jreidinger@suse.cz>
Distribution: SUSE Linux Enterprise 15
```

I have also noticed that [this libzypp page](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libzypp) says,

> There is no official package available for openSUSE Leap 15.4

Is there any way I can solve this issue and make zypper (and Yast) work again?

Comment: You have done something wrong, it should work. However, a grep on my system suggests that you need to install `libyaml-cpp0_6-0.6.3-150400.4.3.1.x86_64.rpm` I would also make sure that your repos reference 15.4 as they may still be on 15.3. If so, then delete the 15.3 ones.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give us an update on the issue? I've got the same error and rpm -q displays exact same version of zypper and libzypp. Wondering if a working solution was found?
Thank you!

Update: Found and executed an rpm command from this article and zypper is back to working order: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000020725

Steps suggested there:

```
sudo rpm -Uhv https://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.4/sle/x86_64/\
libyaml-cpp0_6-0.6.3-150400.4.3.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/447972)